# How to divide rows within the same dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a three-column data frame; I have managed to calculate the total population for each year using groupby (e.g. the last two rows are the total for country C and D for each year). Now how to calculate the percentage of each country's population over the whole population for each year.

```
country,year,population
C,1952,100
C,1957,200
D,1952,160
D,1957,290
W,1952,260
W,1957,490
```

Desired output would be:

```
country,year,percentage
C,1952,100/260
C,1957,200/490
D,1952,160/260
D,1957,290/490
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you adding the year total , just try `transform`

```
df['pct'] = df.population/df.groupby('year')['population'].transform('sum')
```

Comment: thanks. Really need to look into how `transform` works